# attempting to do two checks into one xpath rule in drools

Tags: xml, drools

The following rules work on their own

```
rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH"</pre>
when
    xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "1"
then 
    Log : "ReminderSend";
    Destination : "ReminderSend";
end 

rule "Routing Rule to Send using XPATH"
when
    xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "0"
then 
    Log : "Send";
    Destination : "Send";
end

rule "Routing Rule to NoSend using XPATH"
when    
    xpathMatch "/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='SHIP']"
then 
    Log : "NoSend" ;
    Destination : "NoSend";
end
```

Unfortunately i have one more variable that i need to check for in the first two rules and i'm checking for `/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='PICKUP']`. I have attempted the following that work on their own but not in the combination with two rules

```
xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0"
xpathMatch "/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='PICK-UP']"
```

Ideally the below code is what i need to get to work

```
rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH"
when
    xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "1" 
    xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0"  
then 
    Log : "ReminderSend";
    Destination : "ReminderSend";
end 

rule "Routing Rule to Send using XPATH"
when
    xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "0"
    xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0"
then 
    Log : "Send";
    Destination : "Send";
end

rule "Routing Rule to NoSend using XPATH"
when    
    xpathMatch "/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType ='SHIP']"
then 
    Log : "NoSend" ;
    Destination : "NoSend";
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the file XPathLanguage.dsl which contains the definitions for xpathMatch/Equals/GreaterThan/LessThan. This domain specific language (DSL) translates some

```
xpathMatches "xpath"
```

into a Drools rule CE (I simplify somewhat):

```
msg: Message( type == MessageType.JBOSS_XML ) 
and 
eval( DslHelper.xmlContentMatches(msg, "{xpath}") )
```

This looks like the syntax of some rather old Drools version - the "and" wouldn't be needed in a newer version. Therefore, combine two or more of the xpathXXX forms using "and":

```
rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH"
when
  xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0" 
  and
  xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "1" 
then 
  Log : "ReminderSend";
  Destination : "ReminderSend";
end

rule "Routing Rule to Send using XPATH"
when
  xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0" 
  and
  xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "0"
then 
  Log : "Send";
  Destination : "Send";
end
```

Comment: You can add the rule "Routing Rule to NoSend using XPATH" - then the four rules are the equivalent of the three rules you said you need.

Comment: there something wrong with my syntax still               #rule "Routing Rule using XPATH"

rule "Basic1"
 when
  xpathGreaterThan  "count(/OrderLineList/OrderLine/Order[@OrderType = 'PICK-UP'])", "0"   
 then 
 end 

rule "Routing Rule to ReminderSend using XPATH" extends "Basic1"
 when
  xpathEquals  "count(/OrderLineList[(@IsPICKUPReminder)])", "1"
 then 
  Log : "ReminderSend";
  Destination : "ReminderSend";
 end

Comment: this is in esb so the errors are very hard to troubeshoot 2014-12-23 14:39:12,360 WARN  [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (pool-173-thread-1) No fault address defined for fault message! To: InVMEpr [ PortReference < <wsa:Address invm://4e59434f2d4f4d532d43617465676f72792d76335f302424242424242424242424245069636b5570436f6e6669726d6174696f6e5f5033/false?false#10000/>, <wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:type : urn:jboss/esb/epr/type/invm/>, <wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:passByValue : false/> > ] MessageID: 8139a1be-5ee5-4bd6-818f-c354d02d7068
i'm thnk rule def incrt

Comment: when i see this error i know its breaking inside the drool file

Comment: I've found some documentation - this is JBoss ESB. Will try to find s.th. on rules. May take time, and its getting late. Will be back tomorrow.